# Issue trying to concat a variable with a string inside an html tag on Twig

Tags: templates, twig, concatenation

im trying to edit this code from a prestashop template in order to change the href of the link into mailto:$contact_infos.email instead of writing manually the email there. I have been looking about how to concat on Twig and people use ~ inside {{ }} but here doesn't work. If anyone could help me with this would be awesome.

Thanks in advance.

```
{* [1][/1] is for a HTML tag. *}
            {l
              s='[1]%email%[/1]'
              sprintf=[
                '[1]' => '<a href="mailto:mail@mail.es">',
                '[/1]' => '</a>',
                '%email%' => $contact_infos.email
              ]
              d='Shop.Theme'
            }
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? This is the right way. What is displayed? Do you have an error?

Comment: i have tried multiple versions of this:

Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty Compiler: Syntax error in template "module:ps_contactinfo/ps_contactinfo.tpl" on line 50 "'[1]' => '<a href="{{'mailto:' ~ $contact_infos.email}}">'," - Unexpected "mailto", expected one of: "","" , "]" <-- thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\agrodomingo\vendor\prestashop\smarty\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php on line 50

@sengadev